# How to stop one Python script that runs continuously on linux

Tags: python, linux, multithreading

I have multiple Python scripts that is running and continuously in linux one of them used to monitor devices in my network that contain threading and while true function and if there is anything goes down it will send me message on telegram bot.

my database are changing every day and I'm using "crontab -e" command to kill the script every morning by using [ kill -9 -l <program_name.py> ] and run the script after 1 minute but every day the number of messages increased by one like it never kill the threading process of yesterday.

I'm currently logged on Linux through PuTTy and am doing all the coding there. So, is there a command in linux to completely stop one python script and leaves the others?

Comment: How does this question relate to `C` or `gcc`?

Answer (score 0):

did you try put "sys.exit()" in your last line or last function?

```
...
sys.exit()
```

or, you can try kill the process itself:

```
...
os.system('kill $PPID')
```